# Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 apache http/2 not working after upgrade

Tags: apache2, lamp, php7

I upgraded my server to the LTS release. mod_http2 seems to be broken under apache2 with PHP7.2.

```
The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
```

How do I get this running? Is this issue under development?

Comment: Here's the Apache 2.4's documentation for various [MPM modules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html) choose the one you prefer and change your apache configuration file to reflect that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is that http2 using the mpm prefork module is not supported under 18.04 LTS at the moment. The work around is to use a different mpm module with apache2.